# writing empty shared string into cell openxml

Tags: c#, xml, excel, openxml

I am trying to write shared string into cell, however, after the code is running. I found the hyperlink cell are empty with text. But the hyper link is there.

```
string[] words = data.Split('!');

string cellReference = string.Format("{0}{1}", columnText, rowIndex);
string uniqueID = "hyperlink" + linkIndex.ToString();
Hyperlink hyperlink1 = new Hyperlink() { Reference = cellReference, Id = uniqueID };
hyperlinks1.Append(hyperlink1);
wsPart.Worksheet.Save();
wsPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new System.Uri(attachmentDownloadURL + "?id=" + words[0].ToString(), System.UriKind.Absolute), true, uniqueID);

// add hyperlink text to shared string table
shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(words[1])));
shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Save();

cell.CellReference = cellReference;

cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(linkIndex.ToString());
cell.StyleIndex = styleHyperlink;
linkIndex++;
}
```

Anything is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't get what you mean by **`empty with text`**? kinda contradiction in terms.. isn't it?

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous meaning. I mean the cell do not display any text.